# Reactjs / MaterialUI 3: Select into table row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Reactjs and MaterialIU v.3 ***(remember v3 not v4)***, I'm trying to implement a Table using `[array].map` to building it, and rendering a `Select` inside `TableCell`, expecting to define a specific percentage by separate for each service (lunch, snack, transportation), but when I've changed anyone, the selected percentage changes all the selector. Have anyone an idea to achieve the approach.

Codes & image:

```
<Table className={classes.table}>
                        <TableHead>
                          <TableRow>
                            <TableCell>Code</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Value</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>Perc.</TableCell>
                          </TableRow>
                        </TableHead>
                        <TableBody>
                          {this.state.fees_details.map((item, key) => {
                            return (
                              <TableRow key={key}>

                                <TableCell>
                                  {item.ItemCode}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                  {item.Dscription}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                  {item.Price}
                                </TableCell>
                                <TableCell>
                                  <Select
                                    value={this.state.percentControl}
                                    onChange={this.selectItemOnChange}
                                    inputProps={{
                                      name: item.ItemCode,
                                      id: item.ItemCode
                                    }}>

                                    <MenuItem value={0}>0%</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={10}>10%</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={20}>20%</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={30}>30%</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={40}>40%</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={50}>50%</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={60}>60%</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={70}>70%</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={80}>80%</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={90}>90%</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value={100}>100%</MenuItem>
                                  </Select>
                                </TableCell>

                              </TableRow>
                            ) })}
                        </TableBody>
```

And my function `selectItemOnChange` definition is:

```
selectItemOnChange(e) {
    console.log(e)
    if (e.target.name === '0024') {
      console.log(e.target.value)
      this.setState({
        percentControl: e.target.value
      })
    }
    if (e.target.name === '0025') {
      console.log(e.target.value)
      this.setState({
        percentControl: e.target.value
      }) 
    }
    if (e.target.name === '0027') {
      console.log(e.target.value)
      this.setState({
        percentControl: e.target.value
      }) 
    }
  }
```

Image:
[image]

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it happen as well as using one single value of status.

Make it an Object or an Array.

You can pass the identity index as params in the handler function.

Below is a minimal reproducible example which you can refer

```js
const list = [...Array(10).keys()].map(x => ({ id: x, ItemCode: x }));
const App = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState(list);
  const onChangeHandler = id => e => {
    setSelected([
      ...selected.filter(x => x.id !== id),
      { id: id, ItemCode: e.target.value }
    ]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {list.map(item => (
        <select
          key={item.id}
          value={selected.find(x => x.id === item.id).ItemCode}
          onChange={onChangeHandler(item.id)}
        >
          <option value={0}>0%</option>
          <option value={1}>10%</option>
          <option value={2}>20%</option>
          <option value={3}>30%</option>
        </select>
      ))}
      <br />
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.12.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I gonna try it. I'm not using hooks and functional components, just Class component, but it helps and drives me an idea. Let you know how it works.